# Bash/Expect script echo result wrong

Tags: bash, echo, expect

I'm writing a bash script to log onto a network device via telnet using expect to retrieve device status information. Everything is working fine and I get the result as expected from the device however, when trying to echo the result in a sentence like, it get's a bit scrambled.

Here is my bash script with the outputs indicated:

```
#!/bin/bash

hostName=$1

INT=$(expect -c '
set timeout 1
set userName admin
set password password

spawn telnet '$hostName'

expect "..."
expect "Connected to"
expect "'^]'."
expect "Username:"
send "$userName"
send "\r"
expect "Password:"
send "$password"
send "\r"
expect "admin@telnet"
expect ">"
send "vsp power"
send "\n"
expect "admin@telnet"
expect ">"
send "exit"
' | grep - | awk '{print $3}')

echo "$INT"  # basic output showing indeed the correct value return from $INT

echo "vspP $INT | vspP=$INT""V"  # the preferred output to allow logging
```

The first echo displays the basic result as being correct. The second echo has the output scrambled as can be seen by the output results below:

```
# ./vsppower.sh 192.168.0.12
23.67
VvspP=23.67
```

The actual output preferred would be:

```
vspP 23.67 | vspP=23.67V
```

Please provide assistance how I could correct this echo output.

Comment: What does `set | grep ^vspP` show? Is `echo "vspP $INT | vspP=$INT""V"` really the actual complete command?

Comment: Try this `echo "vspP $INT | vspP=${INT}V"`

Comment: @konsolebox, the `echo "vspP $INT | vspP=$INT""V"` is the output I would need at this time. Please explain more on `set | grep ^vspP`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, the `echo "vspP $INT | vspP=${INT}V"` gave the exact same result: `VvspP=23.67`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a Carriage Return or other weird character embedded in your string somewhere. To try and find it, do this:

```
set | grep -i INT | cat -vet
```

The `set` will show all your environment variables and the `grep` will find the specific one you want. Then `cat -vet` will show any weird characters in there, e.g. `^M` for Carriage Return.

There is a carriage return at the end of $INT. Try adding this line after the end of your `expect` script and before you use INT

```
INT=$(tr -d '\r\n' <<< $INT)        # Strip linefeeds and returns
```

It uses `tr` with `-d` to delete linefeeds and carriage returns.

Comment: Thanks Mark for the advise. The set command was placed right after the second echo and gave the following result `BASH_SOURCE=([0]="./vsppower.sh")$
_=$'vspP 23.67\r | vspP=23.67\rV'$`.

Comment: the output I got is as follows: `BASHOPTS=cmdhist:extquote:force_fignore:hostcomplete:interactive_comments:progcomp:promptvars:sourcepath$
INT=$'23.67\r'$
SHELLOPTS=braceexpand:hashall:interactive-comments$
`. Unfortunately I don't fully understand the output. Please continue advising. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please have another look - I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much Mark, your answer did indeed resolve the issue. I will also add that while awaiting more feedback I did figure that the `\r` didn't look right and used cut command to just use the first five characters by updating the line after the expect exit command with: `' | grep - | awk '{print $3}' | cut -c1-5 )`. When I wanted to post this, you already updated your answer which I did test your answer which worked perfectly. I will use your answer as I have multiple scripts with answers of various lengths. Many thanks for your assistance, it is greatly appreciated!!